# How infer certain property from nested objects as union?

Tags: typescript

I have next object with question, and inside each question I have property answer, so how
can I inver it as union types?

**Example:**

```
const data = {
  question1: {
    answer: 'answer1',
  },
   question2: {
    answer: 'answer2',
  },
  question3: {
    answer: 'answer3',
  },
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
type Key = 'answer1' | 'answer2' | 'answer3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably better solutions would exist.
But this will be an answer.

```
const data = {
  question1: {
    answer: 'answer1',
  },
   question2: {
    answer: 'answer2',
  },
  question3: {
    answer: 'answer3',
  },
} as const

type Key = typeof data[keyof typeof data]['answer']
```